# Building a dropdown based on another dropdown in php

Tags: php

New in php and ajax, building a dropdown based on another dropdown through database.Up to now code is sucessfully running, you can check my code having two php pages, dropdown2.php and postbrand.php now just want to know how to use $brand variable value in postbrand.php to use in the sql query in second dropdown in dropdown2.php.

```
    <?php  
     require 'connect.inc.php';
     $query = "SELECT * FROM `brand`  ";
     $data = mysql_query($query);
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Input form</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
     <label>Brand:</label>
     <select name="brand" id="sb" onchange="myFunction()">
     <?php
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($data))
     {
    ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row['b_name'];?>">
    <?php 
     echo $row['b_name'];

      ?>
     </option>
     <?php
     }
    ?>
    </select>       
    <br/><br/>
    <label>Model:</label>
    <?php  
    $query = "SELECT model.model, model.b_id from model inner join brand on model.b_id= brand.b_id where brand.b_name like 'sony'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $select= '<select name="select" id="sm">';

    while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($result)){              $select.='<option                                                 value="'.$rs['b_id'].'">'.$rs['model'].'</option>';

        }

     $select.='</select>';
     echo $select;
     ?>
     </form>

    <div id="result"></div>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        //alert('working!!');

        var brand = $('#sb').val();

        $.post('postbrand.php', {postbrand:brand},

            function(data){

                    $('#result').html(data);

            });
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>


    postbrand.php

    <?php 

     $brand = $_POST['postbrand'];
     echo $brand;

     ?>
```

Comment: The $brand variable is holding the value of first dropdown, if any how i can use the variable in place of sony in my sql query in the second dropdown my code will work

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correct you want to populate the second dropdown based on the chosen value of the first dropdown.

To steps to achieve this are:
listen to "change" event on the first dropdown (using JQ)

```
var selected = ""
$('select#sb').on('change', function() {
  selected = $(this).val(); // get the chosen value
});

 $.post("postbrand.php", selected, function(resp){ //send the selected value to postbrand.php which will return an array of elements from db based on what was selected
      $.each(resp,function(key, val){ //traverse the response and
          $('select#secondDropdown').append('<option>'+val+'</option>') //populate the 2nd dropdown
      })
 })
```